# Rails Generator (array)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and Postgres. How do I generate this migration with the rails model generator?

```
add_column :notes, :tags, :string, array: true, default: []
```

I would like to do something like

```
rails g model name:string tags:string:array
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To make a change in the database, you have to generate a new migration.

```
$ rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
```

In your case:

```
$ rails generate migration add_tags_to_notes name:string
```

Currently you can't pass a default value to this command:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers

So a migration file change is required.